# Learning Algorithms on myself, how do you implement tuples in java?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm teaching myself algorithms and I'm sorry if my title is incorrect! I don't understand how to implement this in Java.

```
if x = 0: 
return (q,r) = (0,0) 
(q, r) = divide(⌊x/2⌋, y)
q=2·q, 
r=2·r
if x is odd: r=r+1 
if r≥y: r=r−y, q=q+1 
return (q, r)
```

I don't know how to implement the following parts in Java.

```
(q,r)=(0,0)
(q,r)=divide(⌊x/2⌋, y)
return (q,r)
```

Comment: This kind of thing in Java would be implemented as a class with two fields. Therefore it would help if you told us a bit more about your application and the classes you have currently...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although Java lacks built-in support for tuples, good news is that you do not have to use tuples to implement this algorithm, except for the return value. Two regular `int` variables `r` and `q` will do.

```
// (q,r)=(0,0)
int q = 0, r = 0;
// (q,r)=divide(⌊x/2⌋, y)
q = (x/2) / y;
r = (x/2) % y;
```

Returning is a bit tricky, because you have to return two values. Idiomatic way of doing it in Java is defining a class:

```
class QandR {
    private final int q;
    private final int r;
    public QandR(int q, int r) {
        this.q = q;
        this.r = r;
    }
}
```

Now you can return `new QandR(q, r)` from your method.

Comment: If I wanted to implement the first one for the return part would it be something like


    return new int[] {q, r}

Comment: @user3561871 Using an array in place of a tuple is OK for private methods, but it lacks intuitivity of a named class for methods that you expect others to call. For private methods `return new int[] {q, r}` will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! I posted my effort on the algorithm. :)

Comment: @user3561871 return type of the method has to be `public static int[] division(int x, int y)` with square brackets.

Comment: You sir are incredible! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You could use either an array or a class instance to contain and return more than one values. E.g.
`(q,r)` where both `q` and `r` are of type `int`

```
int[] qrTuple = new int[2]; // zero initialized
```

or

```
class QrTuple {
    int q, r;

    QR(int q, int r) {
        this.q = q;
        this.r = r;
    }
}
```

and then

```
QrTuple qrTuple = new QrTuple(0, 0);
```

in both cases you can do at the end of a method :

```
return qrTuple;
```